# how to create folder as admin in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm working on a project where we generating folders for users, my question is that is it possible to create those folders with one particular user as admin in code behind?

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + compamyFolder + "/User/" + folder)))
  {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + compamyFolder + "/User/" + folder));
  }
```

Comment: Post your code so far. If you don't have any, delete the question and have a go first.

Comment: We need to create the folders as a specific user, not the one we are logged in with, in this case : admin.  Is it possible like that?

Comment: You've missed my point, and you're being lazy. -1.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code as per http://forums.asp.net/p/1226236/2209871.aspx:

```
string subPath ="ImagesPath"; // your code goes here

bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

if(!isExists)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score -1):

how about

```
string folderPath = @"C:\myRootFolder";
if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
 {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
 }
```